# a GET request to localhost gives an internal server error

Tags: windows-7, drivers, localhost

The problem:

I am trying to use Intel's driver & support assistant.
I have the application installed on my Windows,
but it opens a webpage that makes a GET request to my localhost , that request gives an internal server error.

What I have tried:

I disabled my firewall,
my AVG antivirus,
also my adBlockers for that page,

and when I open the URL in the GET request http://127.0.0.1:28385/intel/v1.0/detect/getproductsanddownloads?language=en&country=us&jsver=19.12.50.1

it gives me one word "Forbidden"
, even when I change 127.0.0.1: to localhost:
but still same error

why would my localhost give such an error?

[a screenshot of GET request error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZfxD.jpg)

Comment: Is your system set to use a proxy by chance? Since this is an application, it'll be using system-level settings. Check `Internet Options` in your control panel, go to `Connections`, and click on `LAN Settings`.

Comment: @MikeyT.K. no I have checked it, no proxy

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to reproduce this problem on my end.

The localhost connection is to a service that DSA installs on your system.

If you have not already, try uninstalling and reinstalling DSA. This may render the next step unnecessary.

If that didn't work, open your services panel (Start -> run -> `services.msc`) and ensure that "Intel(R) Driver & Support Assistant` is started. Try restarting it if it is already started.